# JSLink Client-Side Rendering Not Functioning on Custom List

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, column, jslink

I tested out the use of JSlink on the homepage with a demo list & it worked fine.

[image: Home Page]

I then used the same JSLink on the Demo List itself but images did not render.
[image]

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

~site/Webparts/JSLink/JSLinkFieldTemplateBase.js|~site/Webparts/JSLink/JSLinkFieldTemplateExt.js

```
function listItemClick() {
    $(".status-image").on("click", function () {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-val");
        alert("STATUS: " + status);
    });
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(listItemClick);

(function () { 
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {}; 
    overrideContext.Templates.Fields =
    {
        'Status': { 'View': overrideTemplate }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext); 
})();


function overrideTemplate(ctx) {
    var status = ctx.CurrentItem.Status;
    var image = "";

    if (status == "Delayed")
        image = "http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-Delayed.png";
    if (status == "On-time")
        image = "http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-Ontime.png";
    if (status == "Late")
        image = "http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-Late.png";

    return "<img class='status-image' src='" + image + "' data-val='" + status + "' />";
}
```

Updated to:

```
function listItemClick() {
    $(".status-image").on("click", function () {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-val");
        alert("STATUS: " + status);
    });
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(listItemClick);

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
            Fields: {
                'Status': { 'View': overrideTemplate }
            }
        }
    });
});

function overrideTemplate(ctx) {
    var status = ctx.CurrentItem.Status;
    var image = "";

    if (status == "Delayed")
        image = "http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-Delayed.png";
    if (status == "On-time")
        image = "http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-Ontime.png";
    if (status == "Late")
        image = "http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-Late.png";

    return "<img class='status-image' src='" + image + "' data-val='" + status + "' />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your template is not applied since `clienttemplates.js` library is not yet loaded when `SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides` function is invoked.

Instead of

```
(function () { 
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {}; 
    overrideContext.Templates.Fields =
    {
        'Status': { 'View': overrideTemplate }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext); 
})();
```

try to enclose it using `SP.SOD.executeFunc` function:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
              Fields: {
                 'Status': { 'View': overrideTemplate }
              }
        } 
    });
});
```

---

If [Minimal Download Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx) feature is **activated**, then you could utilize `RegisterModuleInit` function to register template as demonstrated below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

        // overrides go here

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/yourtemplate.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

Follow [Register CSR-override on MDS enabled SharePoint 2013 site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site.aspx) for a more details.

Comment: I updated the code to the above but that did not work.

Comment: Is Minimal Download Strategy feature is activated on web site?

Comment: It is currently set to active. Should I deactivate it?

Comment: Aha, yep, first option would be to deactivate it (simplest one) and the second option would be to invoke template as demonstrated here (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888923/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p) see RegisterModuleInit function

Comment: I would try just to deactivate MDS feature

Comment: Deactivating did not work. I'll have a read over the Code Project article tomorrow and see how I get on. :)

Answer (score 0):

JSLink is great but not the only solution.

Your code can easily be put in a Calculated Column; if set to output as Number it will evaluate the HTML and display the IMG

```
"<IMG src=""http://URL/sites/Main/Testing/Webparts/JSLink/Status-"&[Status]&".png"">"
```

By the looks the only image name you have to rename is On-time

Comment: in share point 2016 now it is deprecated. or this feature in calculated column is disabled by micro soft.

Comment: correct; see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110